# is it possible to add 2 different mx recorId of entry of different registrar in a single domain?

Tags: email, mx-record

Im having a mail id in google apps for business for one or my domain.since my user accounts has been full (reached 10 users per account).so that i bought yahoo mail service.
is it possible to keep both google and yahoo mx in a single domain?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Technically - yes. You can have as many MX records you like.

It will not work in practice though. Mail servers who are trying to send you mail does not know which server holds whose mailbox. In other words, if user joe has his mailbox on google apps and a mail server tries to deliver it to yahoo it will get denied, unless joe also has a mailbox on yahoo.

Stop being a cheapskate and just upgrade your account :-)

Comment: :) Its not for me..for one of my client.they already buy the service.
what can i do to made this happen?

Comment: you can't @pauska is right this isn't possible